# Send (post) an image from one application to another (get) by URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, rest

I need to send a picture from one asp.net application to another. My receiver is an asp.net MVC application, but the sender can be a simple console application.

Senario

Application one has a link to an image and send/post this to application two by URL.

Application two receives/get the image and saves it to a folder on the server.

I have heard of REST, asp.net web api and web service but not found any tutorial how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Application #2, the receiver,  has to have REST Web API which accepts a file (an appropriate mime type) and saves it, that's it.